# How can I blacklist an asset in a rails 3.X app (no stub_asset) using a custom Sprockets processor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I am creating a custom processor, which needs to dynamically blacklist some files as it loads them. In particular, I am adding two directives "allow" and "restrict". Here is an example of the setup:

./manifest.js

```
#= allow Group1
#= require_tree .
```

./some_included_file.js

```
#= restrict Group1
```

./some_other_file.js

```
#= restrict Group2
```

In the above case, the manifest.js is loaded, and attempts to load some_included_file and some_other_file. However, because of the "allow Group1" directive, only the first file should be bundled, and the other one should not because of the Group2 restriction (which wasn't allow'ed).

Below is what I have so far:

```
class CustomProcessor < Sprockets::DirectiveProcessor

  def process_allow_directive group

    unless defined? self.context.environment.custom_allow_list
      self.context.environment.class.module_eval { attr_accessor :custom_allow_list }
    end

    self.context.environment.custom_allow_list ||= []
    unless self.context.environment.custom_allow_list.include? group
      self.context.environment.custom_allow_list += [group]
    end
  end

  def process_restricted_directive *groups

    groups.each do |group|
      if defined? self.context.environment.custom_allow_list
        if self.context.environment.custom_allow_list.include? group

          # Allow the file to be included
          # Don't intervene
          return
        end
      end
    end

    # File is restricted, prevent loading, but....
    # ....HOW ??

  end
end

Rails.application.assets.register_preprocessor('application/javascript', CustomProcessor)
```